# Raft ，why the newer leader's term is bigger than older one

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, raft

[how raft follower rejoin after network disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568168/how-raft-follower-rejoin-after-network-disconnected)

Just the same as it.
However, will the log in machine 0 replaced by machine 1?
The committed log after machine 0 left will be nothing?
Machine 1 has a greater term, and it will be the leader.
There must be something to make new leader's term greater than ever before.
Tell me please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "RPC time" << "time out", so the older leader' term must smaller than the newer one.
And there is one thing called "Raft prevote".